# can't catch exception after creating CXIndex

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010, libclang

Why does this program

```
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    try {
        throw std::exception("threw");
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    CXIndex idx = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
    clang_disposeIndex(idx);
    return 0;
}
```

behave as expected, but this one

```
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    CXIndex idx = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
    clang_disposeIndex(idx);
    try {
        throw std::exception("threw");
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

crashes?

More generally, what could a function do that causes subsequent exceptions to not get caught?

Using: visual c++ 10.0 (tried the different /EH flags), clang 3.4 (built with the same)

Comment: One of those `clang_*()` functions might be throwing an exception, try moving both those calls into the `try` block.

Comment: @Praetorian No exception is thrown in the first program. Just in case I moved them inside the try block with the same result.

Comment: Add `catch(...){ cout << "Another exception" << endl; }` after the first catch block, you'll know whether some other exception is being thrown then.

Comment: @splrs Same result. I stress that the first program does *not* crash. The same function calls are being made in the second one, just in a different place.

Comment: Are you sure the first one isn't crashing as well, but displaying the message before it's before the CXIndex variable's declaration? Put the clang stuff in its own try-catch block and see if there's an exception in both cases.

Comment: The first program does not crash. How exactly does the second program crash? Is this "Unhandled std::exception" or something else?

Comment: @splrs I'm sure the first one doesn't give me a box saying "test.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience." Just in case I tried putting the clang calls in their own try/catch (...) block: no exception is caught.

Comment: @AlexFarber Looks like it's an unhandled exception 0xc0000005 (access violation)